# Add column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a silly problem. My `df` looks like this:

```
       FID_2     STA_SID           s2            s1  Qh_STA  Qh_FID2  \
14 222143.00 26040713.00           0.00        0.00    8.00    17.00   
15 222143.00 26040713.00           0.00        8.00    6.00    17.00   
13 222143.00 26040713.00           6.00        8.00    3.00    17.00   
17       NaN 26033594.00 29445425.00        1707.00    5.00      nan
```

I defined the following function and command:

```
A = 0.8

def seekDO(row):
       if (row['Qh_STA'])/row['Qh_FID2'] < A :
          return 1
       if ((row['Qh_STA'] + row['s1'])/row['Qh_FID2'] < A) :
          return 1
       if ((row['Qh_STA'] + row['s1'] + row['s2']) / row['Qh_FID2'] < A) :
          return 1
       return 0

df['DO'] = df.apply (lambda row: seekDO(row),axis=1)
```

The problem is that for `DO` I get

```
    DO   
14  1  
15  1  
13  1  
17  0
```

Instead of

```
    DO   
14  1  
15  0  
13  0  
17  0
```

Can you perhaps see where I got mistaken?

Comment: not related to the error but `df.apply (lambda row: seekDO(row),axis=1)` is the same as `df.apply (seekDO,axis=1)`

Comment: If test first condition get values `<A` with `print ((row['Qh_STA'])/row['Qh_FID2'])` - `0.47058823529411764, 
0.35294117647058826, 
0.17647058823529413`

Comment: All your cases fall into the first `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you can test each condition with all columns instead looping, what is slow:

```
A = 0.8

m1 = df['Qh_STA']/df['Qh_FID2'] < A 
m2 = (df['Qh_STA'] + df['s1'])/df['Qh_FID2'] < A
m3 = (df['Qh_STA'] + df['s1'] + df['s2']) / df['Qh_FID2'] < A
```

Then need chain columns with `AND` by `&` for matched if all conditions are `True`:

```
df['DO'] = (m1 & m2 & m3).astype(int)
print (df)
       FID_2     STA_SID          s2      s1  Qh_STA  Qh_FID2  DO
14  222143.0  26040713.0         0.0     0.0     8.0     17.0   1
15  222143.0  26040713.0         0.0     8.0     6.0     17.0   0
13  222143.0  26040713.0         6.0     8.0     3.0     17.0   0
17       NaN  26033594.0  29445425.0  1707.0     5.0      NaN   0
```

Comment: I apologize. Could you please repeat for the edited df in the beginning? This explains why my expected output was 1 0 0

Comment: But your answer is correct. The `DO` column is such as I expect to get

Answer (score 1):

Maybe np.where;

```
condition = ((df['Qh_STA'])/df['Qh_FID2'] < A) | (((df['Qh_STA'] + (df['s1'])/df['Qh_FID2']) < A)) | (((df['Qh_STA'] + df['s1'] + (df['s2']) / df['Qh_FID2']) < A))

df['DO'] = np.where(condition, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

But you should get

```
    DO   
    14  1  
    15  1  
    13  1  
    17  0
```

indeed.

Take a look at your values again.

```
    8 / 17 IS < 0.8
    6 / 17 IS < 0.8
    3 / 17 IS < 0.8
```

The output is correct, what you expect to get as output is not.

Comment: In the second row there's a condition `8+6` and in the third `8+6+3`

Comment: But you return the value *BEFORE* even reaching that condition.
You don't even reach that condition in your code. Add some print()s to see what is happening.